# How to find the archetype of maven project in eclipse?

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

I am planning to create a new project but I want to understand the archetype of existing maven project. So that I can follow the same archetype while creating a new one. 
i have tried many things one of them was web.xml but still not working for me. I would appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For a Maven project, there is no general way to find out from which archetype it was created.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mvn archetype:create-from-project`

Reference: http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/advanced-usage.html

Comment: Thanks hament, as I am new to maven and springMVC ,I am not able to get